# HTML align justify: width parameter?

Tags: html, justify

I am working in an environment where I can only edit a text-string. I can use xhtml in the text string, but have no access to css or any other layers. (I'm a hobbyist)

Inside a large box (800px wide) I want a smaller justified text (350px wide)

My attempt:
`<p width="350px" align="justify">`Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architec`</p>`

Doesn't work. The paragraph tag works. Justify works, but to the full width. Width in pixels, percent or absolute numbers doesn't work.

Any tips / workarounds?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't use inline styles either?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to

```
<p style="width:350px; text-align:justify;">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architec</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

Style="text-align:justify; width:350px;"

Inline styles should work.

Comment: He's looking for width not justify...
style="width: 350px;"

Answer (score 0):

What about using inline styles.

```
<p style="width:350px; text-align:justify;"> your text..... </p>
```